# ffmpeg -acodec not found but installed

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to change a video url from youtube to a mp3 via ffmpeg so I can stream the response in Ubuntu 14.04

```
 ffmpeg -i https://r7---sn-ab5l6ne7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video%2Fmp4&requiressl=yes&signature=99EFD8B801C44EA1221B5D653B2EB30C4CE962C6.6CD123737E54A11B0E5B16BC7AA2572688B091D9&source=youtube&mn=sn-ab5l6ne7&upn=2c_sPjXh1FE&itag=22&pl=16&mt=1450291179&ms=au&expire=1450312883&mm=31&id=o-ABMSf6BaCXTeSmFM41vs85JJ2rmcdeD6CVriiGKVMDlG&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&ip=68.9.161.152&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&key=yt6&lmt=1429526600478294&dur=6.385&fexp=9416126%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9423459%2C9423662&mv=m&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=2147500 -acodec liblamemp3 -f mp3 shave.mp3
```

But when I run this command, I end up with this issue

```
ffmpeg -i https://r7---sn-ab5l6ne7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video%2Fmp4&requiressl=yes&signature=99EFD8B801C44EA1221B5D653B2EB30C4CE962C6.6CD123737E54A11B0E5B16BC7AA2572688B091D9&source=youtube&mn=sn-ab5l6ne7&upn=2c_sPjXh1FE&itag=22&pl=16&mt=1450291179&ms=au&expire=1450312883&mm=31&id=o-ABMSf6BaCXTeSmFM41vs85JJ2rmcdeD6CVriiGKVMDlG&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&ip=68.9.161.152&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&key=yt6&lmt=1429526600478294&dur=6.385&fexp=9416126%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9423459%2C9423662&mv=m&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=2147500 -acodec liblamemp3 -f mp3 shave.mp3[19] 8925
[20] 8926
[21] 8927
[22] 8928
[23] 8929
[24] 8930
[25] 8931
[26] 8932
[27] 8933
[28] 8934
[29] 8935
[30] 8936
[31] 8937
[32] 8938
[33] 8939
[34] 8940
[35] 8941
[36] 8942
[37] 8943
[38] 8944
[39] 8945
[40] 8946
[41] 8947
ffmpeg version git-2015-12-10-3652dd5 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-gnutls
  libavutil      55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavcodec     57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavformat    57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 20.100 /  6. 20.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
-acodec: command not found
[20]   Done                    requiressl=yes
[21]   Done                    signature=99EFD8B801C44EA1221B5D653B2EB30C4CE962C6.6CD123737E54A11B0E5B16BC7AA2572688B091D9
[22]   Done                    source=youtube
[23]   Done                    mn=sn-ab5l6ne7
[24]   Done                    upn=2c_sPjXh1FE
[25]   Done                    itag=22
[26]   Done                    pl=16
[27]   Done                    mt=1450291179
[28]   Done                    ms=au
[29]   Done                    expire=1450312883
[30]   Done                    mm=31
[31]   Done                    id=o-ABMSf6BaCXTeSmFM41vs85JJ2rmcdeD6CVriiGKVMDlG
[32]   Done                    sver=3
[33]   Done                    ratebypass=yes
[34]   Done                    ip=68.9.161.152
[35]   Done                    sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire

[19]+  Stopped                 ffmpeg -i https://r7---sn-ab5l6ne7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video%2Fmp4
[20]   Done                    requiressl=yes
[21]   Done                    signature=99EFD8B801C44EA1221B5D653B2EB30C4CE962C6.6CD123737E54A11B0E5B16BC7AA2572688B091D9
[22]   Done                    source=youtube
[23]   Done                    mn=sn-ab5l6ne7
[24]   Done                    upn=2c_sPjXh1FE
[25]   Done                    itag=22
[26]   Done                    pl=16
[27]   Done                    mt=1450291179
[28]   Done                    ms=au
[29]   Done                    expire=1450312883
[30]   Done                    mm=31
[31]   Done                    id=o-ABMSf6BaCXTeSmFM41vs85JJ2rmcdeD6CVriiGKVMDlG
[32]   Done                    sver=3
[33]   Done                    ratebypass=yes
[34]   Done                    ip=68.9.161.152
[35]   Done                    sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire
[36]   Done                    key=yt6
[37]   Done                    lmt=1429526600478294
[38]   Done                    dur=6.385
[39]   Done                    fexp=9416126%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9423459%2C9423662
[40]   Done                    mv=m
[41]   Done                    ipbits=0
```

Now I am not sure why it keeps spitting this out.  I have tried to do a streaming output with '-' variable as well and still no avail.

I have installed ffmpeg, and all the dependencies.  I used [this bash script](https://gist.github.com/xdamman/e4f713c8cd1a389a5917) to compile ffmpeg.  I have been trying for days to get this working and still cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah that fixed the issue.  Now I will post the programming issue.  thank you

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: why didn't you vote to close and migrate the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put double quotes (`"`) around the input URL. See [FFmpeg Documentation: Quoting and Escaping](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping).